# Извечный вопрос

Tags: грамотная-речь

Он /она/оно/победит - есть;
Ты победишь - есть;
Мы победим - есть; 
Они  победят - есть. 
Короче, все есть, кроме первого лица, единственного числа (т.е я + глагол "побеждать" в совершенном виде).  Возникает вопрос (у меня лично) - почему?

Answer (score 1):

Ожидаемые формы первого лица у глагола "побеждать" будут "побежду", "побежу" и "победю". Все три неблагозвучны, поэтому их и не рекомендуют использовать.
До революции "побежду" было вполне литературным словом, даже у Л. Н. Толстого встречалось.

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что некоторые глаголы *ограничены* в образовании или употреблении личных форм (их поэтому называют **недостаточными глаголами**).
В современном русском языке существуют морфологические нормы образования форм слов.
 С точки зрения их соблюдения у глагола «победить» не образуется форма 1 лица единственного числа будущего времени.
При необходимости употребления этого глагола при местоимениях 1 лица используется *описательная конструкция **вспомогательный глагол + инфинитив**:*
надеюсь победить
стараюсь победить
смогу победить
попытаюсь победить
хочу победить.

Формы глаголов «победю», «побежу» и «побежду» не являются нормативными. Заменим их описательными конструкциями ***«одержу победу», «смогу победить»***.
У ряда глаголов русского языка также не существует формы 1 лица единственного числа настоящего или будущего времени. В этом перечне упомянем следующие глаголы:
**бороздить, дерзить, дудеть, затмить, мутить, очутиться, ощутить, приютить, убедить, чадить, чудить, шелестеть.**
При образовании форм 1 лица этих глаголов в разговорной речи возникает морфологическая ошибка.

Однако, *Борис Акунин* пишет в своём блоге ( 22.12.2010 ):
Расшатывать основы бытия я не готов.
*А вот за глагольную форму «побежду» еще, пожалуй, поборюсь.*

И приводит выдержки из «Пространной русской грамматики» Греча (1830 г.) и из «Русского правописания» академика Грота (1902 г.),  где *" я побежду " присутствует.*

Историк Лев Прозоров утверждает, что при Петре на знаменах писали **"Сим мечом побежду враги моя"**, и приводит доказательство:
https://www.drive2.ru/b/2843749/

Вполне возможно, что когда-нибудь форма "я побежду" вернется в язык.